# is there a solution to push an item to array in async function in node js?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

this is my node js code:

```
try {
        const basket = await Basket.find({user_id: user._id})
        if (!basket) {
            return res.status(404).send({msg: "not found"})
        }
        let products = [];
        await basket.map(item => {
            const product = Product.find({_id: item.product_id})
            products.push(product)
        })
        console.log(products)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    }
```

I need to push product with specific ids to `products` array and send it as a response but the `products` array is []  in output. I will be thankful if anybody helps me.

Comment: Does Product.find need to have an await?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$in` operator to match all product ids by one query,

- you can map basket item and return an array of `product_id`s

```
let products = await Product.find({ 
  _id: { $in: basket.map(item => item.product_id) } 
});
console.log(products);
```